# Ruby on Rails: named scope with lambda and an array

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
named_scope :all_public, lambda { |users| 
       { :conditions =>  ["visibility = ? || (visibility = ? && user_id = ?)", Shared::PUBLIC, Shared::PRIVATE, users] }
     }
```

That works nice for one user, but is there a way to modify it to work where users is an array of user ids?

Comment: Is that really `||` and `&&` and not `OR` and `AND`?

Comment: When I learned SQL, I used the symbols instead of the words. =\ but I guess MySQL can do both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this and then just pass a single element array for the single ID case

```
named_scope :all_public, lambda { |users| 
       { :conditions =>  ["visibility = ? OR (visibility = ? AND user_id IN (?))", Shared::PUBLIC, Shared::PRIVATE, users.join(',')] }
     }
```

Comment: I think you'd need to collect the id's for that to work: users.collect(&:id).join(',')

Comment: @mark Yes you'd be correct if the argument was an array of `User` objects but I understood from the question that it would be an array of IDs. Either way, I agree, the caller must do the `collect` either before or inside the named scope

Comment: You're right, if it were to have worked for a single user then it would also have needed an id. Naming convention is to blame. :)

Comment: shhh. naming some stuff is hard. (not here, but like named scope with two parameters where the visibility can change and so can the user_ids object) =p

Comment: actually this isn't what I want. =( posting more specific question soon.